# Problema checkbox "seleccionar todo" con páginador y suma de valores

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, datatables, checkbox

Tengo una tabla dinámica mostrando registros de mysql (`id,producto,cantidad,precio`), cada registro tiene un `checkbox` y otro `checkbox` **"marcar/desmarcar todos"**, que me hace la suma de los productos listados y los muestra en un `input:text` llamado **total**.

La tabla dinámica tiene un paginador ya que se cargan muchos registros de la base de datos, los `checbox` funcionan perfectos y hacen la suma;

El problema empieza cuando paso a la página 2 de la tabla dinámica el checkbox "marcar/desmarcar todos" queda activo de la primera página y cuando lo desmarco me quita la suma hecha en la primera página, los checkbox de cada registro si funcionan perfectamente cuando paso a la siguiente página, acá dejo el código que amablemente una usuario de acá me hizo, el paginador que estoy usando se llama `DataTables`.

Gracias de antemano.

```js
let buys = document.getElementById('tbl-buys');
let cboxAll = buys.querySelector('thead input[type="checkbox"]');
let cboxes = buys.querySelectorAll('tbody input[type="checkbox"]');
let totalOutput = document.getElementById('total');
let total = 0;

[].forEach.call(cboxes, function (cbox) {
  cbox.addEventListener('change', handleRowSelect);
});

cboxAll.addEventListener('change', function () {
  [].forEach.call(cboxes, function (cbox) {
    //cbox.checked = cboxAll.checked;
    cbox.click();
  });
});

function handleRowSelect (e) {
  let row = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
  let qty = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(3)').textContent;
  let price = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(4)').textContent;
  let cost = Number(qty) * Number(price);

  if (e.target.checked) {
    total += cost;
  } else {
    total -= cost;
  }

  total = Number(total.toFixed(2));
  totalOutput.value = total;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tbl-buys').DataTable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" data-page-length='2' id="tbl-buys">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
      </th>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
      </td>
      <td>Laptop Dell XPS 15</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>782.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
      </td>
      <td>Mouse bluetooth solar</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>19.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
      </td>
      <td>Sony Headphones 1000px</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>29.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
      </td>
      <td>Intel x99</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>200.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<label>Total</label>
<input type="text" id="total" class="form-control" readonly value="0.0" />
```

Comment: Hola, no entendí bien tú pregunta.

Comment: Creo que pude dar con la solución, leyendo en la página de DataTables desactive el botón de ordenar por la columna 0 (la del checkbox), y ahora si cuando cambio de página si me hace la suma sin alterar la suma que había hecho en la página anterior.

Comment: Mi pregunta es, supongamos que tienes 100 productos paginados de a 25, es decir, un total de 4 páginas... al activar el `checkbox`, el total ¿debería ser la suma de los 100 o solo de los 25 listados en la página actual?

Comment: Hola, pues lo ideal sería que al marcar el `checkbox` sumara los 100 productos listados en las 4 páginas.

Comment: Hola, ¿alguna solución para este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En base a este comentario:

> pues lo ideal sería que al marcar el checkbox sumara los 100 productos listados en las 4 páginas.

Una posible solución sería la siguiente:

- Cuando se hace `click` en el `checkbox` del encabezado (`thead`), buscamos los datos de todos registros de la tabla (`dt.data()`), y dependiendo de si está o no `checked`, los sumamos y check-eamos; o dejamos el total en cero y descheck-eamos.
- Cuando se hace `click` en el `checkbox` de un registro (`tbody`), buscamos las datos solo de ese registro y si dependiendo de si está `checked`, sumamos o restamos al total.

Así por ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let $dt = $('#tbl-buys');
  let dt = $dt.DataTable({
    order:[[1, 'asc']],
    columnDefs: [{
      targets: 0,
      orderable: false
    }]
  });
  let $total = $('#total');
  
  // Cuando hacen click en el checkbox del thead
  $dt.on('change', 'thead input', function (evt) {
    let checked = this.checked;
    let total = 0;
    let data = [];
    
    dt.data().each(function (info) {
      var txt = info[0];
      if (checked) {
        total += parseFloat(info[3]);
        txt = txt.substr(0, txt.length - 1) + ' checked>';
      } else {
        txt = txt.replace(' checked', '');
      }
      info[0] = txt;
      data.push(info);
    });
    
    dt.clear().rows.add(data).draw();
    $total.val(total);
  });
  
  // Cuando hacen click en los checkbox del tbody
  $dt.on('change', 'tbody input', function() {
    let info = dt.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
    let total = parseFloat($total.val());
    let price = parseFloat(info[3]);
    total += this.checked ? price : price * -1;
    $total.val(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" data-page-length='2' id="tbl-buys">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </th>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
      </td>
      <td>Laptop Dell XPS 15</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>782.49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
      </td>
      <td>Mouse bluetooth solar</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>19.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
      </td>
      <td>Sony Headphones 1000px</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>29.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox"/>
      </td>
      <td>Intel x99</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>200.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<label>Total</label>
<input type="text" id="total" class="form-control" readonly value="0.0" />
```

Comment: Hola, muchisimas gracias, me funciono perfecto.

Comment: Hola, buenas noches, tengo un pequeño problema que me surgio reciente, resulta que por cada registro listado en la `DataTables` necesito enviar un valor que saco de la base de datos, esto lo haría a traves de los `checkbox` algo así `echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="certificado[]" value="'.$certificado.'"/></td>'`, resulta que cuando hago el envio de los datos a traves del formulario el array con los valores de los `checkbox` seleccionados no llega, revisando el código que me pasaste vi que el `info[0]` me reemplaza los `checkbox` de la `DataTable` que tiene el valor de BD.

Comment: Habrá alguna manera de que cuando le de al `checkbox` de **marcar/desmarcar todos** me tome los valores de los `checkbox` seleccionados y los coloque en un array en JavaScript para agregarlo al `info[0]` que me reemplaza los `checkbox` de la `DataTables`, no sé si es muy confusa mi petición, de ante mano muchas gracias y disculpa las molestías.

Comment: Hola y muchas gracias por la ayuda de verdad lo aprecio, y disculpa tanta molestía, apenas estoy aprendiendo en el JS. Hay otro problema, solo me toma el valor de los `checkbox` en la primera página del `datatables`.

Comment: Listo, entonces haré otra pregunta gracias.

Comment: @Marcos no funciona tu código, no hace nada. Tengo este código:  
 var tabla = $("#ubicaciones").DataTable({order:[[0, 'asc']],
    columnDefs: [{
      targets: 0,
      orderable: false
    }]
  });
  
  $(tabla).on('change', 'tbody input', function() {
    var info = tabla.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
    console.log(info);
  });

Comment: @JorgeAlonso Hola! el ejemplo en mi respuesta aún funciona, por lo que imagino que en tu código debes tener algún otro problema. Recuerda que siempre puedes crear una nueva pregunta con el problema que tienes.

Comment: Hola @Marcos cuando selecciono el checkbox que selecciona todos me sale error que dice "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined", he copiado tu mismo ejemplo pero con la diferencia de que yo lo lleno desde un json mi datatables.

Comment: Hola @Marcos yo solo quería la funcionalidad de seleccionar todo solo comente que yo llenaba mi tabla desde un json.