# ¿Problema en checkbox "seleccionar todo" en mi datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

Hola a todos tengo una consulta y es la siguiente: He agregado un checkbox a mi datatable en `<thead>` para que al seleccionar se activen todos los checkbox del `<tbody>` use un ejemplo de otra pregunta, pero en este caso yo lo lleno de un json la tabla pero no funciona el `checkbox` para que se seleccione todo.

Url de una pregunta de referencia
[https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50247/problema-checkbox-seleccionar-todo-con-p%c3%a1ginador-y-suma-de-valores/53463#53463](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50247/problema-checkbox-seleccionar-todo-con-p%C3%A1ginador-y-suma-de-valores/53463#53463)

Url realizando la misma funcionalidad
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/snqw56dw/3182/)

Ajax producto.json

```
[
    {
        "Producto":"Leche",
        "Cantidad":50,
        "Precio":3.20
    },
    {
        "Producto":"Azucar",
        "Cantidad":40,
        "Precio":2.20
    },
    {
        "Producto":"Gaseosa",
        "Cantidad":14,
        "Precio":6.50
    }
]
```

Código

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" data-page-length="2" id="tbl-buys">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                    </th>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
        <label>Total</label>
        <input type="text" id="total" class="form-control" readonly value="0.0" />
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'producto.json',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(json) {
                        crearTabla(json);
                    },
                });

                function crearTabla(datos) {
                    let $dt = $('#tbl-buys');
                    let dt = $dt.DataTable({
                        data: datos,
                        order: [[1, 'asc']],
                        columns: [
                            {
                                render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                                    return "<input type='checkbox'/>";
                                },
                            },
                            { data: 'Producto', orderable: false },
                            { data: 'Cantidad', orderable: false },
                            { data: 'Precio', orderable: false },
                        ],
                        columnDefs: [
                            {
                                targets: 0,
                                orderable: false,
                            },
                        ],
                    });
                    let $total = $('#total');

                    // Cuando hacen click en el checkbox del thead
                    $dt.on('change', 'thead input', function(evt) {
                        let checked = this.checked;
                        let total = 0;
                        let data = [];

                        dt.data().each(function(info) {
                            var txt = info[0];
                            if (checked) {
                                total += parseFloat(info[3]);
                                txt = txt.substr(0, txt.length - 1) + ' checked>';
                            } else {
                                txt = txt.replace(' checked', '');
                            }
                            info[0] = txt;
                            data.push(info);
                        });

                        dt.clear()
                            .rows.add(data)
                            .draw();
                        $total.val(total);
                    });

                    // Cuando hacen click en los checkbox del tbody
                    $dt.on('change', 'tbody input', function() {
                        let info = dt.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
                        let total = parseFloat($total.val());
                        let price = parseFloat(info[3]);
                        total += this.checked ? price : price * -1;
                        $total.val(total);
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Las url mostradas funcionan bien pero ellos no llenan la tabla desde un json solo lo agregan con codigo html y yo quisiera hacerlo con datos de un json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se debe a que no has adaptado correctamente el código a tu caso. Los errores que tenes son:

- Los datos en tu caso vienen como objeto, pero en el código los analizas como si fueran arreglos
- A la hora de controlar si una fila esta `checked` (*o no*) necesitas definir una propiedad en el objeto, pero en tu código estas intentando analizar texto sobre una posición inexistente.

### Solución:

Teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, dejo un ejemplo funcional (*con comentarios en línea*) que vas a poder adaptar a tu caso sin ningún problema.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function crearTabla(datos) {
    let $dt = $('#tbl-buys');
    let dt = $dt.DataTable({
      data: datos,
      order: false,
      columns: [{
          render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
            // ACA controlamos la propiedad para des/marcar el input
            return "<input type='checkbox'" + (full.checked ? ' checked' : '') + "/>";
          },
          orderable: false
        },
        {
          data: 'Producto',
          orderable: false
        },
        {
          data: 'Cantidad',
          orderable: false
        },
        {
          data: 'Precio',
          orderable: false
        },
      ]
    });
    let $total = $('#total');

    // Cuando hacen click en el checkbox del thead
    $dt.on('change', 'thead input', function(evt) {
      let checked = this.checked;
      let total = 0;
      let data = [];

      dt.data().each(function(info) {
        // ACA cambiamos el valor de la propiedad
        info.checked = checked;
        // ACA accedemos a las propiedades del objeto
        if (info.checked) total += info.Precio;
        data.push(info);
      });

      dt.clear()
        .rows.add(data)
        .draw();
      $total.val(total);
    });

    // Cuando hacen click en los checkbox del tbody
    $dt.on('change', 'tbody input', function() {
      let info = dt.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();
      let total = parseFloat($total.val());
      // ACA accedemos a las propiedades del objeto
      info.checked = this.checked;
      let price = info.Precio;
      total += info.checked ? price : price * -1;
      $total.val(total);
    });
  }

  crearTabla([{
      "Producto": "Leche",
      "Cantidad": 50,
      "Precio": 3.20
    },
    {
      "Producto": "Azucar",
      "Cantidad": 40,
      "Precio": 2.20
    },
    {
      "Producto": "Gaseosa",
      "Cantidad": 14,
      "Precio": 6.50
    }
  ]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" data-page-length="2" id="tbl-buys">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="checkbox" />
      </th>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<label>Total</label>
<input type="text" id="total" class="form-control" readonly value="0.0" />
```

Comment: Estimado @Marcos si funciona el seleccionar todo, pero al deseleccionar todo se desaparecen los datos.

Comment: Si funciono @Marcos habia quítado unas cosas, gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Estimado @Marcos como podría obtener los valores de la fila de acuerdo al 
 seleccionar el check del tbody

Comment: @Dum, actualmente los estas obteniendo cuando haces `let info = dt.row($(this).closest('tr')).data();`, es decir, en `info` están los datos de la fila seleccionada

Comment: Hola @Marcos  como puedo obtener los datos de las filas seleccionadas del checkbox al dar click con un botón.